# Is there an easy way to export a CSV file of all transactions from a specific address or wallet?

Tags: wallet, transaction, address

Is there an easy way, without writing code, to export a CSV file of all transactions from a specific address or wallet? (not Daedalus)

Comment: If you're using Nami you can use this https://github.com/Et9797/tx-history-viewer

Answer (score 0):

Address or wallet?

The distinction is important for UTXO chains following the [BIP-44 standard](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), because a single extended public key (wallet key) can generate a virtually infinite number of addresses. Are you looking to query a *single* one of these addresses, or *all* of the addresses associated with a single wallet?

In the case of the former, I am unaware of any easy third party solution for TX export by individual addresses. If there are none, the only option would be to query from an API endpoint like [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/), or to query from your own [db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync) instance.

In the case of the latter however, light wallets (like [Eternl](https://eternl.io/app/mainnet/welcome)) have easy export options for the entire wallet history. You do not have to fully restore your wallet to access these features. You can instead import your wallet as read-only (requiring only the extended public key of the wallet, no signing keys), and export TX history in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. One is with `cardano-db-sync` as mentioned in @zhekson's response.

The other way is by querying the `cardano-wallet` executable (bundled with Daedalus) as per the documentation at https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

# https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/

progname=$(basename "$0")

curl --version > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "${progname}: 'curl' program is missing." >&2 ; exit 1 ; }
jq --version > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "${progname}: 'jq' program is missing." >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

wallet_pid=$(pidof cardano-wallet)
http_port=$(lsof -Pan -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -p "${wallet_pid}" | tail -1 | sed 's/.*://;s/ .*//')


function api () {
  curl --silent --cert ~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/tls/client/client.crt \
    --cacert ~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/tls/client/ca.crt \
    --key ~/.local/share/Daedalus/mainnet/tls/client/client.key \
    "https://localhost:${http_port}/v2/$1"
}

function wallets () {
  api wallets | jq '.[] | {name: .name, id: .id, state:.state.status, pool:.delegation.active.target, balance: (.balance.total.quantity / 1000000) }'
}

function transactions () {
  echo "TransactionId,Timestamp,Direction,AmountAda"
  api "wallets/$1/transactions" \
    | jq -r '.[] | [.id, .inserted_at.time, .direction, .amount.quantity / 1000000] | @csv' \
    | sort --field-separator=',' --key 2
}

function usage_exit {
  echo
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "  $progname wallets                   - List the known wallets."
  echo "  $progname transactions <wallet>     - List all transactions for a given wallet."
  echo
  exit 0
}

case "${1:-""}" in
  wallets)
    wallets
    ;;
  transactions)
    shift
    if test $# -eq 1 ; then
      transactions "$1"
    else
      echo
      echo "Error: A wallet needs to be specified."
      usage_exit
      fi
    ;;
  *)
    usage_exit
  esac
```